# Can a character shove or grapple while prone?

Tags: dnd-5e, grapple, prone

This is similar to the question "[Can a character shove an enemy who is already prone?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/147561)". If your character is prone, can you grapple or shove an enemy in range? I haven't read anything that says you *can't* shove or grapple while prone, but I wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### You are able to shove or grapple while prone.

The *Basic Rules* outline the [prone condition](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Prone):

> - A prone creature's only movement option is to crawl, unless it stands up and thereby ends the condition.
> - The creature has disadvantage on attack rolls.
> - An attack roll against the creature has advantage if the attacker is within 5 feet of the creature. Otherwise, the attack roll has disadvantage.

Nothing here says you *can't* grapple or shove while prone.

Reading through the rules for [grappling](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Grappling) and [shoving](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#ShovingaCreature), there is nothing there either which would prevent you from grappling or shoving while prone.

Note: while the rules for prone say "The creature has disadvantage on attack rolls", *grapple and shove do not use attack rolls*! Instead, each of these say that "instead of making an attack roll", you make a Strength (Athletics) check. So you don't even have disadvantage to grapple or shove while prone!

Comment: "You don't have disadvantage" is misleading. The rule about disadvantage on attack rolls while prone doesn't apply, but the DM has several good reasons to apply disadvantage anyway.

Comment: @MarkWells That’s entirely your opinion which I disagree with.

Comment: If Hollywood is to be believed, you should have Advantage to grapple or shove while prone; the first thing any character does when knocked down by an opponent is either strike the knee or grab them and drag them down too, then you get the rolling grapple on the ground while they both try to reach a dropped weapon.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but you'll have disadvantage.

The other answer is wrong about not having disadvantage.  Grapple and Shove are both special melee attacks that involve taking the Attack action.  A prone creature has disadvantage on attack rolls , which includes special melee attacks like grapple and shove. So therefore the prone creature has disadvantage on grapple/shove.

Comment: The already-accepted answer includes a quote saying that prone gives disadvantage on attack rolls, and explains that grappling does not use an attack roll.  If you are contending that _any_ attack has disadvantage while prone, you should support this with a quote from rules text or other source.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The rules for shoving and grappling both say “**Instead of making an attack roll**”, indicating that what you are doing is *not* an attack roll.